How to pass the content of a variable to `\pgfkeyssetvalue`?
The shown MWE is mainly derived from here and describes how to calculate a 4 digit hash value. It works as expected apart from two things:

Why does this part of code not work? \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\hashValue} where \hashValue is defined as \edef\hashValue{\calcHash{\valueA\valueB}}? I thought that edef expands everything and there should only be the "hash-string" as input parameter for the \pgfkeyssetvalue function.

How do I have to modify the \setError function and where do I have to put it in, to just print: "The Hash [value of the hash] is duplicated!" as a pdf comment? The comment function is already there, so I just need the correct function call of \setError and an input variable with where the content is the duplicated hash value.


MWE
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[draft]{pdfcomment}%
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712969/104358
% Calculate an alphanumerical hash value
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_mdfive_hash:n { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_range:nnn { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_hex:n { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \msg_error:nnn { nnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { NV }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \clist_if_in:Nn { NV } { TF }

\str_new:N \l__pascals_hash_str
\clist_new:N \g__pascals_hashes_clist
\msg_new:nnn { pascals } { duplicate-hash }
{ Hash~ #1~ already~ used! }
\cs_new:Npn \__pascals_calc_hash_aux:n #1
{
    \int_to_Base:nn
    {
        \int_from_hex:e
        { \str_range:enn { \str_mdfive_hash:e {#1} } \c_one_int { 5 } }
    }
    { 36 }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pascals_calc_hash:n #1
{
    \str_set:Ne \l__pascals_hash_str { \__pascals_calc_hash_aux:n {#1} }
    \str_set:Ne \l__pascals_hash_str
    {
        \prg_replicate:nn { 4 - \str_count:N \l__pascals_hash_str } { 0 }
        \l__pascals_hash_str
    }
    \clist_if_in:NVTF \g__pascals_hashes_clist \l__pascals_hash_str
    { {\setError{#1}}{}}
    { \clist_gput_right:NV \g__pascals_hashes_clist \l__pascals_hash_str }
    \l__pascals_hash_str
}
\NewDocumentCommand \clearHashes {} { \clist_gclear:N \g__pascals_hashes_clist }
\NewDocumentCommand \calcHash { m } { \__pascals_calc_hash:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\setError}[1]{
    %\pdfcomment[icon=Note]{Duplicate}
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Hash;A;B
-;2;3 
-;6;7
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstableset{
    verb string type,
    assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
    every column/.style={
        assign cell content/.code={
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecolname}{Hash}}{
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{A}\of{\csvdata}
                \edef\valueA{\pgfplotsretval}
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{B}\of{\csvdata}
                \edef\valueB{\pgfplotsretval}

                \edef\hashValue{\calcHash{\valueA\valueB}}
                \hashValue

                % Why does this not work?
                % \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\hashValue}

                % This works!
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{123}
            }{}
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
\end{document}

OUTPUT
The output looks like this, for the working part! The non working part is not compiling! As you can see, that hash's are created correctly, but the \pgfkeyssetvalue function doesn't seem to take it in this format.


\edef (which you should never need as you are using expl3) or e will fully expand expandable commands but \calcHash uses \str_set:Ne so makes assignments so is not expandable

Where should the output of \setError be printed to? The terminal or into the PDF?

The following fixes the assignment of your hashes to a variable. For this I changed the way \calcHash works slightly (output inside that macro, not inside the internal function). As a result you can continue to use it as is, but also use the same internal function to set a variable instead of printing the results via the \setHash document command.
You'll also need to expand the value inside of \hashValue, which is done by \ExpandArgs{nV}, or else you'll only set that macro as a value and will have problems with grouping.
Currently this answer lacks your \setError related querry, as I'm not sure what exactly you want.
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[draft]{pdfcomment}%
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712969/104358
% Calculate an alphanumerical hash value
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_mdfive_hash:n { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_range:nnn { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_hex:n { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \msg_error:nnn { nnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { NV }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \clist_if_in:Nn { NV } { TF }

\str_new:N \l__pascals_hash_str
\clist_new:N \g__pascals_hashes_clist
\msg_new:nnn { pascals } { duplicate-hash }
{ Hash~ #1~ already~ used! }
\cs_new:Npn \__pascals_calc_hash_aux:n #1
{
    \int_to_Base:nn
    {
        \int_from_hex:e
        { \str_range:enn { \str_mdfive_hash:e {#1} } \c_one_int { 5 } }
    }
    { 36 }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pascals_calc_hash:n #1
{
    \str_set:Ne \l__pascals_hash_str { \__pascals_calc_hash_aux:n {#1} }
    \str_set:Ne \l__pascals_hash_str
    {
        \prg_replicate:nn { 4 - \str_count:N \l__pascals_hash_str } { 0 }
        \l__pascals_hash_str
    }
    \clist_if_in:NVTF \g__pascals_hashes_clist \l__pascals_hash_str
    { {\setError{#1}}{}}
    { \clist_gput_right:NV \g__pascals_hashes_clist \l__pascals_hash_str }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \clearHashes {} { \clist_gclear:N \g__pascals_hashes_clist }
\NewDocumentCommand \calcHash { m }
  { \__pascals_calc_hash:n {#1} \l__pascals_hash_str }
\NewDocumentCommand \setHash { m m }
  {
    \__pascals_calc_hash:n {#2}
    \str_set_eq:NN #1 \l__pascals_hash_str
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\setError}[1]{
    %\pdfcomment[icon=Note]{Duplicate}
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Hash;A;B
-;2;3 
-;6;7
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstableset{
    verb string type,
    assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
    every column/.style={
        assign cell content/.code={
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecolname}{Hash}}{
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{A}\of{\csvdata}
                \edef\valueA{\pgfplotsretval}
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{B}\of{\csvdata}
                \edef\valueB{\pgfplotsretval}

                \setHash\hashValue{\valueA\valueB}%
                \hashValue

                % Why does this not work?
                \ExpandArgs{nV}\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\hashValue

                % This works!
                %\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{123}
            }{}
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
\end{document}



Slight adjustment of the code printing the error as a \pdfcomment, the only adjustment needed is to forward the hash value instead of the input value to \setError in the \__pascals_calc_hash:n function, and to really use #1 inside of \setError to show the argument.
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[draft]{pdfcomment}%
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712969/104358
% Calculate an alphanumerical hash value
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_mdfive_hash:n { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_range:nnn { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_hex:n { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \msg_error:nnn { nnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { NV }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \clist_if_in:Nn { NV } { TF }

\str_new:N \l__pascals_hash_str
\clist_new:N \g__pascals_hashes_clist
\msg_new:nnn { pascals } { duplicate-hash }
{ Hash~ #1~ already~ used! }
\cs_new:Npn \__pascals_calc_hash_aux:n #1
{
    \int_to_Base:nn
    {
        \int_from_hex:e
        { \str_range:enn { \str_mdfive_hash:e {#1} } \c_one_int { 5 } }
    }
    { 36 }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pascals_calc_hash:n #1
{
    \str_set:Ne \l__pascals_hash_str { \__pascals_calc_hash_aux:n {#1} }
    \str_set:Ne \l__pascals_hash_str
    {
        \prg_replicate:nn { 4 - \str_count:N \l__pascals_hash_str } { 0 }
        \l__pascals_hash_str
    }
    \clist_if_in:NVTF \g__pascals_hashes_clist \l__pascals_hash_str
    { \exp_args:NV \setError \l__pascals_hash_str }
    { \clist_gput_right:NV \g__pascals_hashes_clist \l__pascals_hash_str }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \clearHashes {} { \clist_gclear:N \g__pascals_hashes_clist }
\NewDocumentCommand \calcHash { m }
  { \__pascals_calc_hash:n {#1} \l__pascals_hash_str }
\NewDocumentCommand \setHash { m m }
  {
    \__pascals_calc_hash:n {#2}
    \str_set_eq:NN #1 \l__pascals_hash_str
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\setError}[1]{%
    \pdfcomment[icon=Note]{Duplicate hash: #1}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Hash;A;B
-;2;3 
-;2;3 
-;6;7
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstableset{
    verb string type,
    assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
    every column/.style={
        assign cell content/.code={
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecolname}{Hash}}{
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{A}\of{\csvdata}
                \edef\valueA{\pgfplotsretval}
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{B}\of{\csvdata}
                \edef\valueB{\pgfplotsretval}

                \setHash\hashValue{\valueA\valueB}%
                \hashValue

                % Why does this not work?
                \ExpandArgs{nV}\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\hashValue

                % This works!
                %\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{123}
            }{}
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
\end{document}



Cool! First issue is solved! Regarding the \setError function: When you just explain, where I can put my function call of the '\setError' function and in the best case also give this function an input parameter with the duplicated hash value, then it would be perfect. To answer your comment below the question, at the end I will print a pdf comment with this error message. This seems to be uncommon, but this error is generated by wrong input data at the end, and via this comment the end user is informed what's going on, after my CI environment has build the pdf and send to all participants.

@Pascal you could use a boolean variable to mark the error and then can put your error output where ever you want. I'll add a POC to the answer.

Okay, but I also need the concrete duplicate Hash value in this case.

Isn't it easier just always return the hashValue, but in case of a duplicate also call my \setError function?

@Pascal but that's already done?! The \__pascals_calc_hash:n function will call \setError with #1 being the input for which the duplicate hash was calculated. You can easily change that to the offending hash by changing the #1 when it's called to \l__pascals_hash_str.

You are right, it works now! Just one last question, as I mentioned this right now. I did not expected, that also making the cell content bold will have an impact on the behavior. So could you tell me, how to handle a scenario like: \ExpandArgs{nV}\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont\hashValue} The options \fontseries{b}\selectfont seems to make the issue here.

\ExpandArgs{nV} expects a function, then a normal argument in braces, then a single control sequence which expands it to its Value and leaves that in braces as a second argument to the function. You can't just put \fontseries{b}\selectfont in front of it, that won't work. You can use the following instead \ExpandArgs{ne}\pgfkeyssetvalue{<path>}{\unexpanded{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}\unexpanded\expandafter{\hashValue}}. ne means a normal argument and another argument which is fully expanded, we then protect the stuff from expanding and expand \hashValue once.

Argh... I was on the right way... I tested \ExpandArgs{ne}\pgfkeyssetvalue{<path>}{\unexpanded{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}{\hashValue}}before... but I did not add \unexpanded\expandafter in front of \hashValue. Thanks!
